# Discrepancy between entered and displayed text

Tags: support, status-bydesign, formatting

In my answer to this question ([Simpler input for the new unit support](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15338/simpler-input-for-the-new-unit-support/169858#169858)), I am trying to show that two different lines of code give the same result (490. m).  I thus entered the following text:

[image]

However, I instead got this, in which my second entry of "490. m" is displayed as "491. m":

[image]

I tried deleting the second instance of "490. m" and reentering it, to no avail—the system still displays "491. m".

I get the same result when I add a right-arrow before the second "490. m", as follows:

[image]

However, when I instead write "490 m" (without the period), the anomalous behavior disappears.  But then, to display the results on separate lines, I have to put an additional hard return between the two, and put a right arrow before each.

[N.B.: If you go to to my answer, you won't see the "491. m"; I deleted it to avoid the confusion it would cause.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is not a bug, but running afoul with the Stack Exchange automatic list numbering behavior.  For example below I type "1. item" three times on three separate lines, but presently get as displayed output "1. ... 2. ... 3. ...":

1. item
2. item
3. item

The addition of Quote markdown does not change this:

> 1. item
> 2. item
> 3. item

To get verbatim output you can also include Code markdown (or `<pre>` tags):

> ```
> 1. item
> 1. item
> 1. item
> ```

---

### Addendum

You can create these formats by selecting your output as a whole, then clicking the appropriate buttons at the top of the editing box, or using the matching keyboard shortcuts.  For example for the third format this would be buttons **{}** then **"**, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Since it was not possible for you to use the "edit" link to view the code of this answer here is the first answer section above, verbatim, itself in a `<pre>` block, with the exception of `<pre>` itself as I couldn't remember or figure out how to escape that.

```
I think this is not a bug, but running afoul with the Stack Exchange automatic list numbering behavior.  For example below I type "1. item" three times on three separate lines, but presently get as displayed output "1. ... 2. ... 3. ...":

1. item
1. item
1. item

The addition of Quote markdown does not change this:

> 1. item
> 1. item
> 1. item

To get verbatim output you can also include Code markdown (or PRE tags):

>     1. item
>     1. item
>     1. item
```

Comment: Wanted to look at your code using "edit", but I'm not allowed to.  When I clicked on edit, I got this message:  "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."   Would like to know what your code for verbatim output is [don't know what "Code markdown" means.]

Comment: @theorist Sorry, I did not anticipate that problem.  I wonder of that is a fairly recent change to Stack Exchange.  In any case I'll try to edit my answer to make the code more clear.

Comment: The only problem with the above approaches are that I'm trying to represent output, and they display the text on a gray background instead of a yellow one (I'm trying to follow the convention of gray for input, yellow for output).  Doing what @m_goldberg suggested seems to come closest, since it makes it gray-within-yellow (on MSE-Meta it's pure gray, but on MSE it's gray-in-yellow). And that's good enough for me -- I don't need to make a project of getting pure yellow.   And I'm still happy having accepted yours as the answer, since you provided the added detail explaining what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to get the formatting you want is

> `490. m`
>   `490. m`

which was entered as

```
>`490. m`  
>`490. m`
```

The 1st line has two black spaces after the closing `` ` ``

Comment: Do you actually find this easy by comparison to Ctrl+K, Ctrl+Q?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Yeah.

Comment: +1 in that case, as I trust your experience :-)